# Is there a way I can make my own <StackLayout> component with a few properties set in the constructor?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

My code includes many instances of this:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Spacing="0">
```

I know I can give that a Style but alternatively is it possible to create my own template version something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StackLayout xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             x:Class="Ja.Templates.VStack">
</StackLayout>

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Ja.Templates
{
    public partial class VStack : StackLayout
    {
        public VStack()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Orientation = ..
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, do exactly this.  The XAML isn't needed if you're just going to declare everything in code.  However, StackLayout orientation is vertical by default, so you don't even need to include that.

Comment: Thanks Jason,  do you have any idea of the default for spacing also?

Comment: it's 6.0 -  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.stacklayout.spacing?view=xamarin-forms

Comment: can you mention all of the things that you want in your custom stacklayout so maybe I can quickly make one for you?

Comment: Spacing="0" would be a good start for me and enough.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could create a customlayout that extend **StackLayout**
like this :

```
namespace App8
 {
    class VStackLayout :StackLayout
      {
        public VStackLayout()
         {
           //set attribute
           Spacing = 0;
           Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical;
         }
      }
 }
```

then in the xaml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App8"
         x:Class="App8.MainPage">

   //use your customlayout
   <local:VStackLayout>
      <!--controls here -->

   </local:VStackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score -1):

At least you have to add custom bindable properties, this could be done by creating a custom [Style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/xaml/application)

For example: create an style for your StackLayout on your App.xaml as Resource Dictionary:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style x:Key="stackLayoutBaseStyle" TargetType="StackLayout">
            <Setter Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical" />
            <Setter Property="Spacing" Value="0" />
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

And then simply use it on any StackLayout that you need to have this style

```
<StackLayout Style="{StaticResource stackLayoutBaseStyle}">
...
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: You completely missed where I mentioned in the question that I don't want to do this: "I know I can give that a Style but alternatively is it possible to create my own template version something like this"

Comment: And you completely missed where I mentioned in my answer that at least you need to add custom bindable properties to your stacklayout, the best and most efficient  option is to do it by style.

Comment: Please see the other answer which answers my question without the need for creating a style.

Comment: @Alan2 i understand what you mean, but seems that you don't understand me, do you need any special or custom binding to your layout ? because if not, there's no need to create a custom StackLayout because is more expensive that just create an style.